# $().selectpicker() Not a Function on Dynamic Element Creation by Bootstrap Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bootstrap-select

I use bootstrap select for my drop down list.

If i setup the list on load, it will works good.

**Example:**

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="target">
               <select class="selectpicker" id="select-picker" multiple>
                      <option>Sunday</option>
                      <option>Monday</option>
                      <option>Tuesday</option>
                      <option>Wednesday</option>
                      <option>Thursday</option>
                      <option>Friday</option>
                      <option>Saturday</option>
                </select>
</div>
```

If i try to make that element on dynamically and refresh 
the select picker,

```
  var data = '<div class="col-md-6"><select name="date[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>'+
             '<option>Sunday</option><option>Monday</option>' +
                '<option>Tuesday</option><option>Wednesday</option>' +
              <option>Thursday</option><option>Friday</option><option>Saturday</option></select></div>';

 $('#target').append(data);

 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

It generates the error as,

```
  TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

What's wrong with this code ?

( "Selectpicker" works fine on loading, it's not support on dynamic elements only. )

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Samuel J Mathew could you check now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I have encountered similar error before

> TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function

and it is due to the fact that I was loading jQuery twice. after loading jQuery library for second time, all the Plugins register on jQuery namespace vanish. So this could be the issue here.

Also, you are accessing the element by class name but you are not providing class name in dynamic HTML

Try

```
var data = '<div class="col-md-6"><select name="date[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>'+
             '<option>Sunday</option><option>Monday</option>' +
             '<option>Tuesday</option><option>Wednesday</option>' +
             '<option>Thursday</option><option>Friday</option><option>Saturday</option></select></div>';
```

Notice

```
class="selectpicker"
```

Comment: Yah, i fix that, but issue is "selectpicker not a function" error.
Still i have this.

Comment: make sure that the HTML is properly rendered. Inspect Element and see if the HTML is correct or not

Comment: But it specified as "selectpicker" is not a function !

Comment: in that case, there is probably something wrong with loading scripts. make sure you are not loading jQuery twice because if you load it the second time, all the other plugins will stop working with the error message you listed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class `selectpicker` to your select. Also, you missed quotes on the last line of `data` variable definition. It should look like this:

```
var data = '<div class="col-md-6"><select name="date[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>'+
         '<option>Sunday</option><option>Monday</option>' +
         '<option>Tuesday</option><option>Wednesday</option>' +
         '<option>Thursday</option><option>Friday</option><option>Saturday</option></select></div>';
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1y767zaa/7/) is a working jsFiddle demostration.